# Improve dynamic input fields creation depending array size php

Tags: php, arrays

I want to create some input fields from an array.
I have an array like

```
$info = array("one"   => "one1",
              "two"   => "two2",
              "three" => "three3"
        );

foreach ($info as $key => $value){
  $field.=  "<div class='formcol form-left middle'>  \n";
  $field.=  "  <input type='text' id='".$key."' size='12' name='".$key."' style='width:".$tam."px;'/>\n";
  $field.=  "\t\t\t   <div class='text'>".$value."</div>\n";
  $field.=  "\t\t </div> \n";
}
```

And it does its job very nice, however If the size of array is 6
like

```
$info = array(  "one"   => "one1",
               "two"   => "two2",
               "three" => "three3",
               "four"  => "four4",
              "five"   => "five5",
              "six"    => "six6" 
        );
```

I woul like to change the code I have to create first 3 values of array to create a "div" and then create other "div" with last 3 values, I will have always mod 3 = 0 values, but the problem is to create a new div every 3 used values

How to improve the code? 
I was thinking something like

```
$size = sizeof($info);

foreach ($info as $key => $value){
  //if ($size % 3 ==0)
       $field.=  "<div class='formcol form-left middle'>  \n";
  //else
  //   {
      $field.=  "  <input type='text' id='".$key."' size='12' name='".$key."' style='width:".$tam."px;'/>\n";
      $field.=  "\t\t\t   <div class='text'>".$value."</div>\n";
  //   }
  //if ($size % 3 ==0) 
      $field.=  "\t\t </div> \n";

}
```

so for 0,1,2 it is a new div, then for 3,4,5 is new div etc.
Is it a best aproach to do this?

Comment: just wondering, why are you bothering to output tabs? and your approach looks good to me. you could calculate `$size % 3 == 0` outside the loop (just store it in a variable) to reduce repeated code and, less importantly, save a tiny bit of time.

Comment: it is because a css has this specific thing, just using php to keep some tedious work filling them one by one

Comment: `I woul like to change the code I have to create first 3 values of array to create a "div" and then create other "div" with last 3 values` then finally you create 6 divs, why you need % 3 ?

Comment: actually I meant to create 2 divs, one div for first 3 values, second for last three values, then make a general code for any (% 3 == 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a counter:

```
$counter = 0;
$field .= "<div>";
foreach ($info as $key => $value){
    $counter++;
    if($counter % 3 == 0) {
        $field .= "</div><div>";
    }
    //your code here
}
$field.=  "</div>";
```

Comment: in the part `//your code` I would write `$field.=  "  <input type='text' id='".$key."' size='12' name='".$key."' style='width:".$tam."px;'/>\n";
      $field.=  "\t\t\t   <div class='text'>".$value."</div>\n";`  ?

Comment: Not sure depends on how you want it laid out. But most likely the 4 lines you have inside your `foreach()`

Comment: Or just the middle two, depending on what you are going for.

Answer (score 1):

Change foreach to for - looks cleaner

```
$field .= "<div>";
for ($i=0; $i<count($info); $i++){
    if($i % 3 == 0) {
        $field .= "</div><div>";
    }
    //...
}
$field.=  "</div>";
```